# Javascript function not working correct in IE and Chrome, image not change if image in inside a accordion

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have ASP.NET site. At the master page I have javascript code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            var img = $("img");

            img.each(function (index, element) {
                if (img[index].complete == true) {
                    Pixastic.process(img[index], "desaturate", {});
                }
                else {
                    img.load(function () {
                        Pixastic.process(img[index], "desaturate", {});
                    });
                }
            });
 });
```

I have a pages, where data is loaded from the database. And if in this data have image script do not process this image.

This code working correct in FF and Opera. But not in IE and Chrome

I'm not correct said

```
 <asp:Literal ID="ltlContent" runat="server" /> <- here too data loaded from database (but image change)
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="accordion" style="width: 740px; float: left;">
        <asp:Repeater ID="AccStDp" runat="server"> <- here I use accordion
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">
                        <%#Eval("nameStDp")%></a></h3>
                <div>
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltlcontentPos" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("textStDp") %>' />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

**How work in FF**

[image: How work in FF]

**How work in Opera**

[image: How work in Opera]

**How work in Chrome**

[image: How work in Chrome]

**How work in IE**

[image: How work in IE]

Comment: Use some alerts or chrome debugger to find which line is not working.

Comment: Try putting alerts in at various places in the script to see if they execute.  It can help you find where the script is breaking.

Comment: the line ...img.load(... its not seems right, maybe it is img[index].load

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
window.onload = function () {
    $( 'img' ).each( function () {
        Pixastic.process( this, 'desaturate', {} );
    });
};
```

So, you use the `onload` handler which is called when all the resources have been loaded.

Comment: @Greg The issue may be with the `Pixastic.process` function - it may not support those browsers.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not correct said. I say what, image not change in this browse, if data loaded from database but if image static image changed

Comment: @Greg How do you load the images dynamically from the database? Can you post the code?

Comment: I do not understand your question. How I understand, image not change if image in inside a accordion

Comment: @Greg Where inside the accordion? In your code, I see an H3, an A, and a DIV, but no IMG element...

Comment: <asp:Literal ID="ltlcontentPos" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("textStDp") %>' /> <- here bind content

Comment: @Greg ASP.net code executes on the web-server, and is therefore not useful in our current situation. JavaScript code executes in the browser which receives the HTML source code from the server (not the ASP.net code). Therefore, could you post the resulting HTML code? ("View source" in your browser)